# Error while executing process C:\...\ndk-r19c\ndk\ndk-build.cmd with arguments

Tags: android-ndk

The following errors will occur. I use Android Studio.

Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:...\ndk-r19c\ndk\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:...\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:...\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-28 NDK_OUT=C:/.../build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:...\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib jni_dlib}

'C:\Users\���C' �́A�����R�}���h�܂��͊O���R�}���h�A
����\�ȃv���O�����܂��̓o�b� `�t�@�C���Ƃ��ĔF������Ă��܂���B 'C:\Users\���C' �́A�����R�}���h�܂��͊O���R�}���h�A ����\�ȃv���O�����܂��̓o�b�` �t�@�C���Ƃ��ĔF������Ă��܂���B
make: *** [C:/.../build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/jni_dlib] Error 1

Comment: I don't know how well the NDK toolchains work with paths that contain non-ASCII characters, but you should at the very least avoid using any paths that contain space characters.

Comment: Thank you for replay. I think so too, but I don't know what file contain space characters and what file affect NDK toolchains. Sorry for my poor English.